# Detect <iframe> height and width from inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I doubt this is actually possible but Im prepared to be corrected.

What I need is to be able to detect the width and height of an iframe from within the iframe, so if the iframe `src` is `iframeContent.html` I need to be able to surface the values on this page.

I have no control over the page that hosts the iframe only the contents of the iframe.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays this is as simple as:

```html
<script>
  console.log(innerWidth, innerHeight)
</script>
```

Just make sure to load this JavaScript from within the iframe and it will print the iframe window's width and height in the browser's console.

Answer (score 12):

You can always get the web page dimensions, no matter if the page is loaded inside an `iframe` or a new window it always works the same way. This is a function I've found used to get `window` dimensions, you can also use it to get an `<iframe>` dimensions.

```
function alertSize() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
  window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```

- [source](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)  (thanks Andy E for adding the link)
- [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fMQhh/)

Comment: You really should provide a link to where you copied and pasted your answer from.  That way credit is given where due.  Also, I think we can safely forget about IE 4 when writing code in this day and age.

Comment: window.innerWidth/Height report back the size of the IFRAME,  not the browser (e.g. if the browser window is resized SMALLER than the containing IFRAME,  the browser always reports back the size of the IFRAME)