# Width of page in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a parent page and inside that parent page, there is an iframe that is around half the size of the parent page.

The JavaScript in the iframed page is supposed to get the size of the iframed page and set the size of a text input, but both JavaScript's `document.body.clientWidth` and jQuery's `$(document).width()` are returning the parent page's width.

How do I get the width of the iframed page from scripts inside the iframe (that is, without having to send the iframe width from the parent page to the iframe page with querystrings)? They are cross-domain too.

Comment: post your current code!

Comment: how are you getting width of current page, please post some relevant code.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846132/jquery-get-height-of-iframe-content-when-loaded

Comment: `var thewidth = document.body.clientWidth;
alert(thewidth);
alert(thewidth - 10);
document.getElementById("address").size = thewidth - 10;`

Comment: @Pugazh thats sort of different. i want to get the height of the iframed page inside the iframed page.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this -

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Comment: yes, but that won't help get the width of the iframed page in the iframed page! I know how to make iframes, obviously.

Comment: The similar kind of work is done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808729/detect-iframe-height-and-width-from-inside-the-iframe you can refer this if it works

Answer (score 0):

> The similar kind of work is done here stackoverflow.com/questions/7808729/… you can refer this if it works –  Manoj Singh

Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted!

EDIT: Sorry, after a bit of testing, this doesn't work too well. In jsfiddle it works, but in my page, it only gives me the height accurately.