# Restrict iframe size

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which is to be promoted on other sites. I have set the minimum amount of frame size which is checked via javascript:

```
function check() {
    var w0 = screen.width;
    var h0 = screen.height;
    var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    if ((w0 < 700) || (w < 650) || (h0 < 500) || (h < 400)) {
    window.location = "stop.html";
```

This works, as per our test. However, I have found that users bypass it by embedding the iframe as width/height=0. The script doesn't catch it as it seems to check the actual page's size where it's embedded.

So how to check the frame's size instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function.

```
function alertSize() {
   var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
   if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
      //Non-IE
      myWidth = window.innerWidth;
      myHeight = window.innerHeight;
   } else if( document.documentElement && ( 
      document.documentElement.clientWidth || 
      document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
      //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
      myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
      //IE 4 compatible
      myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
      myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
   }
   window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
   window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```

Good luck!

- [source](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) ([Thanks Andy E and Teneff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808729/detect-iframe-height-and-width-from-inside-the-iframe))
- [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuxedojoe/yahz8a4p/)